# (swift) how to link textfield to button to modify variable

Tags: swift, xcode, textfield, var

I try to modify a var when a user type in a textfield and clic on a button.

I am not sure about what i did on the last line

if some one can help me
thank you,

G

```
class param{
init(){
    chauffeur_nom = "NOM"
    chauffeur_prenom = "PRENOM"
    chauffeur_datenaissance = "DATE DE NAISSANCE"
    chauffeur_npermis = "NUMERO PERMIS"
}
var chauffeur_nom: String
var chauffeur_prenom: String
var chauffeur_datenaissance: String
var chauffeur_npermis: String
}
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }
}
class formulaire: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet var chauffeur_nom : UITextField!
    @IBOutlet var chauffeur_prenom : UITextField!
    @IBOutlet var chauffeur_datenaissance : UITextField!
    @IBOutlet var chauffeur_npermis : UITextField!
    // PARAMETRES PROFIL CHAUFFEUR
    @IBOutlet var Bouton_sauvegarder : UIButton!
    //BOUTON SAUVEGARDER
    @IBAction func Clique_Sauvegarder(sender : UIButton){
        string saisie = chauffeur_nom (chauffeur_nom.text)
    }
}
```

Comment: For the future: It is easier to help you if your code is written in explanatory english. Also it's always good to add a comment in the code section, which line you need help with.

Answer (score 1):

You could define the variable in one of the classes and then modify it like so:

```
var saisie: String?
```

Then in the IBAction:

```
saisie = chauffeur_nom.text
```